# bootstrap 3 cannot change background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have a problem with my school project. I can't set the the background image of the body of my html file. My syntax is correct. I have tried removing the quotes, and I did all the things I've seen on different question-answer websites but still nothing happens. I tried to change the line to "background-color: red;" and it works. But when I use the "background-image:" it won't work. Please help. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Everything else in the css file are working fine.

CSS : (the body{} portion only)

```css
body {
    background-image: url('images/back.jpg');
}
```

my html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Business Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
<link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href ="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="navtop">
  <div class="container"> 
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <div class ="navbar-brand"><img id="logo" src="images/logo2.png"/><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/></div>
   
   <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   </div>
   <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
   
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li id="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li class = "dropdown">
      <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class = "caret"></b></a>
      <ul class= "dropdown-menu">
       <li> <a href = "#">Laptops</a></li>
       <li> <a href = "#">Notebooks</a></li>
       <li> <a href = "#">Components</a></li>
       <li> <a href = "#">Accessories</a></li>
      </ul>
     
     </li> 
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
  
 
 
 
 
 
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>


<script href="js/query.js" type="javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: in your structure, where is the images folder in relation to the css and html files?

Comment: @paul: the images folder is in the same folder as the html. I have a separate folder for the css.

Answer (score 4):

Check to make sure you're pointing at the right URL.

Looks like the style sheet is in a folder called css. You probably need to jump up a level to drill into the img folder. Something like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/back.jpg');

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to be the problem. Thanks, man! That helped a lot!